# wp_post entry returned from sql-query to post_meta

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I try to figure out what is wrong with an sql-query in wordpress, which produces correct output unless there are none returned. If so, it returns one random item from wp_posts instead. 
This is the query:

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_id, post_title, guid, meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta`, `wp_posts` WHERE post_id = ID AND post_status = 'publish' AND `meta_key` = '_start_eventtimestamp' ORDER BY meta_value ASC" );
```

Comment: Why don't you use `get_posts` instead of a custom query?

Comment: I didn't create this, I just want to find the bug. However it might be easier to reconstruct it with get_posts